# Error while installing npm body-parser

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, body-parser

I get the below error while trying to install npm body-parser

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\username\
AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "body-parse
r"
npm ERR! node v4.4.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.3

npm ERR! No compatible version found: mongodb@2.4.9
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! 2.1.13, 2.1.12, 2.1.11, 2.1.10, 2.1.9, 2.1.8, 2.1.7, 2.1.6, 2.1.5, 2.1.
4, 2.1.3, 2.1.2, 2.1.1, 2.1.0, 2.1.0-rc1, 2.1.0-alpha, 2.0.55, 2.0.54, 2.0.53, 2
.0.52, 2.0.51, 2.0.50, 2.0.49, 2.0.48, 2.0.47, 2.0.46, 2.0.45, 2.0.44, 2.0.43, 2
.0.42, 2.0.41, 2.0.40, 2.0.39, 2.0.38, 2.0.37, 2.0.36, 2.0.35, 2.0.34, 2.0.33, 2
.0.32, 2.0.31, 2.0.30, 2.0.29, 2.0.28, 2.0.27, 2.0.26, 2.0.25, 2.0.24, 2.0.23, 2
.0.22, 2.0.21, 2.0.20, 2.0.19, 2.0.18, 2.0.17, 2.0.16, 2.0.15, 2.0.14, 2.0.13, 2
.0.12, 2.0.11, 2.0.10, 2.0.9, 2.0.8, 2.0.7, 2.0.6, 2.0.5, 2.0.4, 2.0.3, 2.0.2, 2
.0.1, 2.0.0, 2.0.0-alpha2, 2.0.0-alpha1, 1.4.40, 1.4.39, 1.4.38, 1.4.37, 1.4.36,
 1.4.35, 1.4.34, 1.4.33, 1.4.32, 1.4.31, 1.4.30, 1.4.29, 1.4.28, 1.4.27, 1.4.26,
 1.4.25, 1.4.24, 1.4.23, 1.4.22, 1.4.20, 1.4.19, 1.4.18, 1.4.17, 1.4.16, 1.4.15,
 1.4.14, 1.4.12, 1.4.11, 1.4.10, 1.4.9, 1.4.8, 1.4.7, 1.4.6, 1.4.5, 1.4.4, 1.4.3
, 1.4.2, 1.4.1, 1.4.0, 1.4.0-rc9, 1.4.0-rc8, 1.4.0-rc7, 1.4.0-rc6, 1.4.0-rc5, 1.
4.0-rc4, 1.4.0-rc3, 1.4.0-rc2, 1.4.0-rc10, 1.3.23, 1.3.22, 1.3.21, 1.3.20, 1.3.1
9, 1.3.18, 1.3.17, 1.3.15, 1.3.14, 1.3.12, 1.3.11, 1.3.10, 1.3.9, 1.3.8, 1.3.7,
1.3.6, 1.3.5, 1.3.4, 1.3.3, 1.3.2, 1.3.1, 1.3.0, 1.2.14, 1.2.13, 1.2.12, 1.2.11,
 1.2.10, 1.2.9, 1.2.8, 1.2.7, 1.2.6, 1.2.5, 1.2.4, 1.2.3, 1.2.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.0, 1
.1.11, 1.1.10, 1.1.9, 1.1.8, 1.1.7, 1.1.6, 1.1.5, 1.1.4, 1.1.3, 1.1.2, 1.1.1, 1.
1.0, 1.1.0-beta, 1.0.2, 1.0.1, 1.0.0, 0.9.9, 0.9.9-8, 0.9.9-7, 0.9.9-6, 0.9.9-5,
 0.9.9-4, 0.9.9-3, 0.9.9-2, 0.9.9-1, 0.9.8, 0.9.8-7, 0.9.8-6, 0.9.8-5, 0.9.8-4,
0.9.8-3, 0.9.8-2, 0.9.8-1, 0.9.7, 0.9.7-3-5, 0.9.7-3-4, 0.9.7-3-3, 0.9.7-3-2, 0.
9.7-3-1, 0.9.7-2-5, 0.9.7-2-4, 0.9.7-2-3, 0.9.7-2-2, 0.9.7-2-1, 0.9.7-3, 0.9.7-2
, 0.9.7-1.4, 0.9.7-1.3, 0.9.7-1.2, 0.9.7-1.1, 0.9.7-1, 0.9.7-0, 0.9.6-23, 0.9.6-
22, 0.9.6-21, 0.9.6-20, 0.9.6-19, 0.9.6-18, 0.9.6-17, 0.9.6-16, 0.9.6-15, 0.9.6-
14, 0.9.6-13, 0.9.6-12, 0.9.6-11, 0.9.6-10, 0.9.6-9, 0.9.6-8, 0.9.6-7, 0.9.4, 0.
9.4-4, 0.9.3, 0.9.2, 0.9.1
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\nodeprojects\contactlistapp\npm-debug.log

Thanks
Mayank

Comment: you need to update your npm

Answer (score 2):

Remove old npm and install npm again inside folder

Answer (score 1):

Clean your npm cache. This problem may surface when npm cache is corrupt and npm is hitting wrong places.

```
sudo npm cache clean
npm cache clean
```

This should clear the error. If it doesn't help update your npm.

```
sudo npm install -g npm
```

This will overwrite the existing global install of npm with the latest version. There is no easy way around this, as you need npm from package managers to install the latest npm. And Package Managers often pack old npms.

Answer (score 0):

I found  "npm ERR! No compatible version found: mongodb". Why did install body-parser cause mongodb error? Have you check out C:\nodeprojects\contactlistapp\npm-debug.log ?